# How to get 'path' from a Swagger specification file

Tags: java, openapi

We creating YAML specification files with such structure:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: MyService
  version: "1.0"
paths:
   /servicepath/myservice:
    get:
      tags:
      - MyService
    ...
```

It looks something like:

```
class OpenAPI {
    openapi: 3.0.1
    info: class Info {
        title: MyService
        ...
        version: 1.0
    }
    externalDocs: null
    servers: [class Server {
        url: /
        ...
    }]
    ...
    paths: class Paths {
        {/servicepath/myservice=class PathItem {
                ...
            get: class Operation {
                tags: [MyService]
                ...
```

I need to get and made some changes with this path: ' ***/servicepath/myservice*** '

How can I get this path using Java?

Comment: Use [Swagger Parser](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/) or any other Java parser for OpenAPI/Swagger files.

Answer (score 0):

In case when someone will be looking for a solution to this:

After parsing spec file to *OpenAPI* type, we can get paths like this:

```
Paths paths = openAPI.getPaths();
```

And after that, each path can be taken like a key from *Map*, because *Paths* extends *LinkedHashMap<String, PathItem>* :

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, PathItem> pathEntrySet : paths.entrySet()) {
      String keyPath = pathEntrySet.getKey()
     }
```